# javascript execute nested ajax call inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

So, I have two code snippets - both of them are executing without errors. Both are meant to do the same thing - loop through a list of words and look up documents these words appear in (SOLR), then pull paragraphs where these words appear from each document. However they don't return the desired result. The first one skips over the nested ajax call (the one inside the for each loop) and if runs the ajax call at all, it's after the main (parent) loop already finished. The second one only works properly if there is an alert there. If the user acknowledges the alert, then the second loop executes correctly. Without the alert, the second loop gets skipped. Can anyone shed some light at what is wrong here. I've tried ajax {complete:...} and ajax{}.done but they didn't work either.
Here is the first snippet:

```js
for (var m = 0; m < definitions.length; m++ ) {
 var url = pathtomyfile;
 var doctitle, docname, docs;
 var htmlBody, pHtml, fullHTML;

 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (result){
   docs = result.response.docs;
  },
  complete: function () {
   $(docs).each (function (){
    var doctitle = this.dc_title_str.toString().replace (/(\.html|\.htm)/, '');
    var docname = filePathToUrl (this.resourcename.toString ());
    var url = decodeURIComponent (docname);
    $.ajax({
     url: url,
     async: false,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (resp){
      fullHTML = resp.toString();
      htmlBody = fullHTML.split (/<body>/)[1].split (/<\/body>/)[0];
      htmlBody = htmlBody.replace (/\s/g, " ").replace (/&nbsp;/g, " ").replace (/(<a id="x\d+?")\/>/g, "$1></a>");
      var pHtml = $(htmlBody).find("#id").parent();
      pHtml = $(pHtml).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
      pHtml = pHtml.replace (/\<a id/g, "#s#").replace (/<\/a>/g, "#e#").replace (new RegExp ("\\b(" + en_word.replace (/\s/g, "(<[^<]+?>| )*")+"(s|ed|ing|es)*)\\b", "ig"), "<span style='background-color:yellow'>$1</span>").replace (/#s#/g, "<a id").replace (/#e#/g, "<\/a>");
      hsnip += "<p><b><i>From " + doctitle + ":</i></b></p> " + pHtml;
     }
    });
   })
  }
 });
}
```

this is the second snippet:

```js
for (var m = 0; m < definitions.length; m++ ) {
 var url = pathtomyfile;
 var doctitle, docname, docs;
 var htmlBody, pHtml, fullHTML;
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (result){
   docs = result.response.docs;
  }
 });
 alert ('ok');
 for (var b = 0; b < docs.length; b ++) {
  doctitle = docs[b].dc_title_str.toString().replace (/(\.html|\.htm)/, '');
  docname = filePathToUrl (docs[b].resourcename.toString ());
  
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest ();

  docname = decodeURIComponent (docname);

  rawFile.open ("GET", docname, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)) {
    fullHTML = rawFile.responseText.toString();
    htmlBody = fullHTML.split (/<body>/)[1].split (/<\/body>/)[0];

    var pHtml = $(htmlBody).find("#id").parent();

    pHtml = $(pHtml).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
    hsnip += "<p><b><i>From " + doctitle + ":</i></b></p> " + pHtml;
   }
  }
  rawFile.send (null);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an async problem, is not the best idea to make AJAX calls in a loop, you can replicate a loop with recursivity though, have the function only make one call, and call the function again when each call is finished, and add a breakpoint with an if that checks if you're finished.

Comment: It definitely does sound like an async - I even put async:false on every call to account for that but the main loop just runs through regardless. I don't know how I would solve that with recursion though. The first call retrieves a list of documents - the call inside is supposed to pull the paragraphs from those documents. Where would recursion be used?